# Azure Pipelines: error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline: wrong number of segments

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I copied an azure-pipelines.yml from one project to another, and it won't build. I've made sure that everything is the same, and the same extensions are installed on both sides...

The old build still works, but the new one does not:

[image: An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. wrong number of segments]

Here's the YAML:

```
# https://aka.ms/yaml
name: $(Build.DefinitionName)_$(GitVersion_InformationalVersion)
pr:
- master
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'    

steps:
- task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@3
  displayName: GitVersion

- powershell: .\bootstrap.ps1
  displayName: 'Restore pre-requisites'

- powershell: .\build.ps1 -OutputDirectory $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName) -SemVer $(GitVersion.InformationalVersion) -Verbose
  displayName: 'Run build script'

- task: richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-PesterRunner-Task.Pester-Task.Pester@8
  displayName: 'Pester Tests'
  inputs:
    additionalModulePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CodeCoverageFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    resultsFile: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\Test-$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.BuildNumber).xml'
    CodeCoverageOutputFile: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\Coverage-$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.BuildNumber).xml'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    testRunner: NUnit
    searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  displayName: 'Publish code coverage'
  inputs:
    summaryFileLocation: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)\Coverage-$(Build.DefinitionName)_$(Build.BuildNumber).xml'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Module'
  inputs:
    ArtifactName: Module
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It turns out this error message indicates the VERSION of the extension was wrong. I have to nominate the message for least helpful ever...

The `GitVersion` task has (finally!) released version **4** and in the Azure Pipeline world, that *apparently* means that v3 is deprecated. Thus, new teams who install that task extension now only have v4 available (although the team where I copied the yaml from still has v3).

The solution was to change the first step to:

```
steps:
- task: gittools.gitversion.gitversion-task.GitVersion@4
  displayName: GitVersion
```

Comment: Check to see if the YAML editor underlines anything in the window. If it does, then create a new task using the wizard. Check to see if the numbers match. I.e., I was using a Yarn task. My YAML said Yarn@2, which was underlined. The new task said Yarn@3. So I removed the new tag, and updated my old one to Yarn@3.

Comment: Yeah, now that we have some validation in the editor, this is a little easier to detect 

Comment: In my case it was a Microsoft owned plug-in, the version in the repo was `@2`, but the `@1` was the only one available on Azure DevOps.